# How to use density kernel estimation for outlier detection?

Tags: kernel, smoothing, outliers, skew

I have a variable called "price", and the distribution of which looks really skewed. I was planning to detect outliers using the kernel density estimates. Any good ideas for this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you're looking for local maximums of low amplitude ?  You could check the kernel density for slope transitions.  A normal distribution should have go POS-NEG.  If your smoothing function is smooth enough your main data should look like this.  Outliers would add additional POS-NEG transition on the slope.

The slope function is calculated similarly to the kernel itself, but use the derivative of the windowing function you chose.

Adjust the smoothing parameter accordingly and remove samples that contribute to a local maximum of excessive amplitude.